# Highcharts 3.0 beta threshold documentation?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, beta

I'm trying to find documentation for the new features (mainly color threshold) and can't seem to find where this is documented outside the [provided jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/YWVHx/)
.

All that is provided is `negativeColor: '#0088FF'`, what I'm looking to do is set the threshold values on a point by point basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of the status (beta) i think there is no official doc till now.

What i read from source code of beta 3.0 highcharts code, there is no multipoint basis for setting the color.

`/**

  * Get the zero plane either based on zero or on the min or max value.

  * Used in bar and area plots

  */`

Found this in source. looks like it just goes with zero OR min OR max. I was looking for a way too with lets say status 'low', 'normal' and 'high'.

Comment: Still no documentation, and it's out of beta :(

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold or http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts